# Renaming the 'build' directory generated by @wordpress/scripts for React development

Tags: scripts, react

When using [@wordpress/scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts) to create a React app for WordPress, the default configuration to build the app is via running one of the following two scripts `wp-scripts build` or `wp-scripts start` (both run from within **package.json**). Both scripts will take the code from the **src** directory and build it into the **build** directory.

I would like to change the destination directory; for example, I would like the result to be in **dist/app** instead of **build**. I found an option to change the source directory; the option is `--webpack-src-dir` (I have not used it, but I think with a little bit of tinkering, I will find out how), however I could not find a way of changing the destination directory. Is this possible?

Thanks.

PS: This is the first time using React with WordPress, so apologies about the simple question.

Comment: `--output-path` can be used for that - from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts), `"build:custom": "wp-scripts build entry-one.js entry-two.js --output-path=custom"` and "*`npm run build:custom` - builds the code for production with two entry points and a **custom output directory**. Paths for custom entry points are relative to the project root*".

Comment: @SallyCJ - Been reading the documentation and even tracing the code, but did not even see this. I will look into it. Thanks so much for pointing me to the right direction. It looks like this will only work if I have multiple entry points for the build. I have to test it and see if it works. (maybe you can add this as the answer, so I accept it for the greater good?)

Comment: `entry-one.js entry-two.js` was just an example, and I'm pretty sure it will work even for a single entry, `wp-scripts build foo.js --output-path=custom` - I already tried it long ago. It's just I would only write an answer after testing it again. So if it works for you, then just write your own answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing this answer after testing the suggestion given by [@SallyCJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/) (thank you for pointing me towards the right direction)

Writing the following entry into the `scripts` section of **package.json** will change both the *source* and *destination* of the React code.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build --webpack-src-dir=path/to/source/dir/ --output-path=path/to/destination/dir/",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

If you'd like to override the default entry point (i.e., use a different file than **index.js** as your entry point), and if this custom entry point file is located in a custom path, then here is how to setup your scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build path/to/source/dir/custom.js --webpack-src-dir=path/to/source/dir/ --output-path=path/to/destination/dir/",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```